# How to make the function (f1...f10) keyboard shortcuts work in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I've noticed that throughout IntelliJ on MacOS, the keyboard shortcuts for anything like command+f2...f10 don't work. Neither do they trigger anything in the OS to the question is what program is catching these keyboard events. Is there any way to force IntelliJ to get them when IntelliJ is open? This happens even if the IntelliJ window is maximized/fullscreen. All other keyboard shortcuts work.

Specs:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-182.4505.22, built on September 18, 2018
Licensed to ****
You have a perpetual fallback license for this version
Subscription is active until January 18, 2020
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.1
```

Comment: Are they detected properly in "Preferences | Keymap" if you use "Search by shortcut" field? Do you have "Use all F1, F2, etc. as standard function keys." option enabled in "System Preferences -> Keyboard"?

Comment: @y.bedrov I did not have that option checked. Once I checked that checkbox, it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As @y.bedrov kindly pointed out, go to System Preferences->Keyboard and select "Use all F1, F2, etc. as standard function keys." option enabled in "System Preferences -> Keyboard". Then it works :)